# How to filter graphql objects based on check if property is higher or lower than a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I've encountered a problem I cannot find a solution to while trying to create a query for a ecommerce page.

I need to filter my product objects by price. I simply need to pass the query a number and make it get all the products which price is lower than the specified number

Product Object

```
Product{
Title,
Price
}
```

Comment: This should be done from your backend server if your graphQL server is connected to it. To do it using graphQL. You can check whether this link is useful. 

Link: https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/8-filtering-pagination-and-sorting/

Comment: Please show us the schema. Where's the field that returns the list of products that you want to filter? Where's the resolver for it that you want to change?

Comment: **if API/BE/server doesn't support filtering then no possibility to do it on query only level** ... you can query all products (usually paginated, if supported, again) and filter it after fetching .... all depends on implementation, using graphql doesn't matter ... query format without API/BE/server supporting SPECIFIC format/args means NOTHING